# Sending whatsapp message using pywhatkit but getting error

Tags: python, pip

Hey I am new to python programming, and I am trying to use Pywhatkit to send a whatsapp message to a particular number at particular time.

This is my code

```
import pywhatkit 
pywhatkit.sendwhatmsg("a number", "Hi", 0, 43 )
```

Here is the error I am receiving on running this code

```
PS D:\PROJECTS\python> python -u "d:\PROJECTS\python\tempCodeRunnerFile.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "d:\PROJECTS\python\tempcodeRunnerFile.py", line 1, in <module>
        import pywhatkit
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
        from pywhatkit.remotekit import start_server
    File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\pywhatkit\removekit.py", line 6, in <module>
        from flask import Flask, request
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Please copy and paste in the error message instead of inserting it as an image. This way, people using screen readers can also know what it says.

Comment: Do you have `flask` installed?

Comment: @baileythegreen Alright, sorry for the inconvenience, I will keep it in my mind next time.

Answer (score 2):

Try installing flask by pasting this in terminal:
`pip install -U Flask`